# Why doesn't Selenium-js send enter key, even if sendKeys works?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, frontend

I have an element `<input>` that I send keys to with `await element.sendKeys("example")`. This works consistently with no problem.

However, when immediately after I send `await element.sendKeys(Key.ENTER)`, nothing happens.

I can fix this by either waiting 1s (ugh), or by sneaking a `await element.click()` between the two sendKeys functions

```
// Only sends the "example"
await element.sendKeys("example")
await element.sendKeys(Key.ENTER)

// Works
await element.sendKeys("example")
await element.click()
await element.sendKeys(Key.ENTER)
```

What could be causing this? I am perplexed, since the first sendkeys works and the second doesn't. Any other `<input>` in the same project works properly. There are no changes in the DOM's `<body>` before and after the click, so it's not as if any props have changed.

Comment: did you try sendKeys("example" + Key.ENTER)? (or Key.TAB)

Comment: @JeremyKahan you can't actually do that, because you get `JavascriptError: javascript error: initialised is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

probably the issue is with synchronization.

have you tried to use explicit wait ?

**demonstration :**

```
const documentInitialised = () =>
    driver.executeScript('return initialised');

await driver.get('file:///race_condition.html');
await driver.wait(() => documentInitialised(), 10000);
const element = driver.findElement(By.css('p'));
assert.strictEqual(await element.getText(), 'Hello from JavaScript!');
```

probably having an explicit wait will resolve this issue.

something like this :

```
let ele = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('p')), 10000);
await ele.sendKeys("example")
await ele.sendKeys("Key.ENTER")
```

Comment: I already use `await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(selector), 10000)`. The `await driver.wait(() => documentInitialised(), 10000);` doesn't help either

Comment: Can you share the URL ?

Comment: Since this is on a private backoffice portal, no :(